# what is this syntax called? (int)(value) casts the same as int(value)

Tags: python, python-3.x, syntax

I saw this in an exercise problem and had never seen this syntax used in Python before. Haven't had any luck googling it

Comment: It's just another way to write it

Comment: `int` is just a type name. Putting it in parentheses doesn't really have any effect.

Comment: @vampiire: Python doesn't have casting, it just has constructors, e.g. the `int` constructor (same as constructing any other type). The parens around `value` are needed for calling the constructor, the ones around `int` are garbage.

Comment: ah i see. thanks for clearing that up @ShadowRanger. now i need to look up the difference between "casting" (as i have known it) and using a constructor (which makes sense now that you mention it)

Comment: i must have been misinformed when learning about these methods. i learned it using the term "casting". the struggles of trying to teach yourself, have to figure out whats valid and what isnt!

Comment: "Casting" has a specific meaning in languages like C, where it typically involves working with primitive data-types. There *are no primitive data types* in Python. While the word "casting" is used as a synonym for "converting", I personally think it is sloppy. But people usually know what you mean by context.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga fantastic information. Thank you for sorting that out. You cleared up another misconception I had about primitive types. Glad I asked this "stupid" question I learned a lot from the comments.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga is the fact that there no primitives and everything needs to be constructed on the go one of the reasons python is consider inefficient compared to other languages and C in particular? That extra processing step I mean

Comment: @vampiire well certainly the fact that everything is an object in Python makes it much less memory efficient than a language like C. Each `int` object uses around 28 bytes of memory (although, small ints are cached in CPython, ameliorating this). Of course, there are primitive arrays in Python, `import array` for example, or the `numpy` library, which lets you achieve a lot of memory efficiency that would be lost using `int` and `float` objects.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks man i will look into reading more about this. i really appreciate your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Parentheses can be used arbitrarily for precedence purposes.

`(int)` evaluates to `int`, which then gets called with `value` as the argument, exactly the same as `int(value)`. It's abusing the extra parens to look like a C-style cast, but it's distinctly unPythonic, style-wise.

A scenario in which this *might* make sense might include parsing a `str` as `int` or `float` based on whether a `.` occurs in the `str`, e.g.:

```
(float if '.' in value else int)(value)
```

Note: Having written it, still ugly, but it illustrates a use for the parens.

Comment: okay so this is *not* a correct style just an abuse? i should use int(value)?

Comment: @vampiire: Yeah. Just use `int(value)`.

Comment: i saw your edit. in this case its more grouping the ternary statement as a "dynamic" method? dynamic in the sense that the method chosen to accept (value) as an argument is decided via a ternary statement

Comment: @vampiire: Yeah. Point is, in the `(int)(value)` case, the parens were pointless; in the example case, the parens are used to separate selecting the constructor to use from the call, so the arguments to the call aren't repeated. Not worth it, but legal.

Comment: thank you. in this particular example it would not work without grouping the ternary constructor selector would it?

Comment: Without the parentheses, it would be equivalent to this expression (with *different* redundant parentheses): `(float) if ('.' in value) else (int(value))`

Answer (score 3):

The `(int)(value)` is the same as `int(value)`. The syntax has no (other) special name. The parentheses are **superfluous** in this case as `(int)` is the same as `int`:

```
>>> (int)
<type 'int'>
>>> (int)('2')
2
```

You should stick with `int(value)` and avoid ambiguity.

Comment: can this be used to pass arguments to other functions / methods as well or only for type-casting?

Comment: @vampiire There isn't really any "type casting" in Python. At least not in the sense of statically-typed langauges like C. Instead, just think of it as passing a value to a function, `int`.

Answer (score 3):

In a nutshell - this syntax is called redundancy.

Lets think about what brackets do first. Here is an example using arithmetic.

```
(3) + (2)
```

I'm sure you're aware that brackets are a higher precedence than `+` - so this expression evaluates to the following;

```
3 + 2
```

If there were something more in the brackets then that would happen first - but as there isn't there is very little point having them.

Now for your example.

```
(int) ("5")
```

The brackets on the left are redundant - and the ones on the right indicate a function call. But first, it would evaluate the brackets that are only acting as brackets.

```
int("5")
```

The two syntax's you point out are identical in behaviour - but there is no reason to use the one with extra brackets as they are redundant.

It is possible that you are currently getting `C` syntax confused where you can cast types using `(type)object`. Please note that there is no such syntax in python - the code you wrote works by coincidence due to the above.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like something mistakenly copied from another language such as C. It's not actually invalid syntax in Python but the parentheses around `int` literally do nothing and are ignored.

Answer (score 2):

Both does the same. In OOP, we call it type casting and concept is similar. Both the syntax does the same thing as below:-

```
a = (int)(34.65)
print(a)
> 34
a = int(34.65)
print(a) 
> 34
```